# Debugging with Xdebug on virtual machine (debian) not connecting to remote_host

Tags: php, linux, apache, xdebug, remote-debugging

**My Environment:**

On a Mac I am running a Debian (jessie) VM with Apache2 2.4.10, PHP 5.6.9 and Xdebug 2.3.3.
The VM has its own IP-address in my LAN and in the Mac's hosts file I entered a hostname for it, so the website in the VM is reachable via the hostname; therefore I configured a vhost in Apache.

**What I am trying to do:**

I need to debug my PHP project on the remote server (VM). So I followed some instructions I found in the web. But unfortunately Xdebug never tries to connect to the remote_host.

**Some more facts:**

my `[xdebug]` section in my `php.ini`:

```
[Xdebug]
; this is commented out, because i received warnings in apache's error.log, that it is allready activated somewhere else
; I found a site in the Web, where somebody says, that this means, the extension is already compiled into my php binary
; even with this line active I face the same behavior
;zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so 
xdebug.remote_enabled = 1 
; this is comented out, because i activated remote_connect_back
;xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.2.106
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1 
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM 
xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/apache2/xdebug_log
```

The `xdebug` section from Output from `php -i`:

```
xdebug

xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.3.3
IDE Key => root

Supported protocols => Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol => $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Since I want to debug with PHPStorm, but it never gets a debug request when I reload the website, I decided to trace the TCP communication. So in the VM I called the following:

```
tcpdump -ni eth0 -n port 9000 -X
```

But unfortunately I never receive any packets concerning port 9000.

Additionally, I made a test with netcat on port 9000:

```
netcat 192.168.2.106 9000
```

Now tcpdump shows the packages flooding from and to the client on port 9000 and if PHPStorm is not listening netcat tells me that the connection is refused.

So after a whole day of googling (yesterday) I could not determine my problem. Please can anybody point my nose in the correct direction.

What am I doing wrong?

And sorry for my poor English.